# Why doesn't vim store `daw`-ed text in any registers

Tags: vim

I faced a problem during the next use case.

```
function name1(a::Matrix, b::Vector)
function name2(a::Matrix, b::Vector)

end
```

I place cursor at `name1` and hit <kbd>daw</kbd>. Then move cursor to `name2` and hit <kbd>caw</kbd>, <kbd>esc</kbd> and check registers with `:reg` there is no `name1` stored there.

Why does this happen and how can I accomplish such a scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your deleted / changed text is less than one line, so it will be moved into the *small delete register* ([`:help quote-`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#quote-)), and nowhere else. Numbered registers (where you probably expected the changes) are only automatically filled with text longer than one line. From [`:help quote_number`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#quote_number):

> Numbered register 1 contains the text deleted by the most recent delete or change command, **unless the command specified another register or the text is less than one line (the small delete register is used then)**.  An exception is made for the delete operator with these movement commands: %, (, ), `, /, ?, n, N, { and }.

So, if you want to keep the small delete, you need to explicitly specify a register for all [but the last] change or delete. For example: `"acaw` [`"1`]`daw`